# Android: Change gateway address of hot-spot

Tags: android, wifi

Is there a way to change the gateway address of the AP hot-spot feature of Android from 192.168.43.1 to something else such as 192.168.43.3 without recompiling anything? I have a rooted Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You are  trying to change the settings that have been hardcoded for android hotspot.

This is from https://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java -

> ```
> private boolean startTethering(ArrayList<String> available) {                                 
>  
>     boolean wifiAvailable = false;                                                            
>  
>     checkAndSetConnectivityInstance();                                                         
>  
>     String[] wifiRegexs = mCm.getTetherableWifiRegexs();                                      
>  
>     for (String intf : available) {                                                           
>         for (String regex : wifiRegexs) {                                                     
>             if (intf.matches(regex)) {                                                        
>  
>                 InterfaceConfiguration ifcg = null;                                           
>                 try {                                                                          
>                     ifcg = mNwService.getInterfaceConfig(intf);                               
>                     if (ifcg != null) {                                                       
>                         /* IP/netmask: 192.168.43.1/255.255.255.0 */                           
>                         ifcg.setLinkAddress(new LinkAddress(                                  
>                                 NetworkUtils.numericToInetAddress("192.168.43.1"), 24));       
>                         ifcg.setInterfaceUp();                                                
>  
>                         mNwService.setInterfaceConfig(intf, ifcg);                            
>                     }                                                                          
>                 } catch (Exception e) {                                                       
>                     loge("Error configuring interface " + intf + ", :" + e);                  
>                     return false;                                                              
>                 }                                                                              
>  
>                 if(mCm.tether(intf) != ConnectivityManager.TETHER_ERROR_NO_ERROR) {           
>                     loge("Error tethering on " + intf);                                       
>                     return false;                                                              
>                 }                                                                              
>                 mTetherInterfaceName = intf;                                                  
>                 return true;                                                                   
>             }                                                                                  
>         }                                                                                      
>     }                                                                                          
>     // We found no interfaces to tether                                                        
>     return false;                                                                              
> }
> ```

Try check out this question:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android

Comment: On Android 11 it seems my gateway IP of my hotspot is changing every time I disable and enable the hotspot, again. So this answer is outdated for the latest Android. The question is now, is there a solution, eventually?